# Bash chunk in RStudio: permission denied to run Python script

Tags: python, rstudio, permission-denied, chunked-encoding

I am trying to run a Python script (`ring_spin_eigenvalues.py`, see the code below) in an .rmd file in RStudio. I am using a bash-type code chunk and calling the script from there. `number_spins` is just the variable, and the script is located in the working directory I have previously set.

```sh
number_spins=3
python3 ring_spin_eigenvalues.py $number_spins
```

However, when I run the chunk I got an error:

```
    Error in engine(options) : 
    /usr/bin/bash: line 1: /c/Users/Luca/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3: Permission denied
    Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> engine
    In addition: Warning message:
    In system2(cmd, code, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) :
    running command '"bash"  -c "number_spins=3
    python3 ring_spin_eigenvalues.py $number_spins"' had status 126
```

The exiting status is 126, so it is like it finds the command (python3) in the directory, but it has no permission to execute it. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance to everyone!

Luca

Comment: It looks like you only posted the error message, and not your code.

Comment: Thanks Shane, you are right and I've posted it now!